# template declaration cannot appear at block scope

Tags: c++, c++11

so this is for my class and, to be frank, I've never used templated before. Here is my simple vector.h file, but I keep the getting error that templates can not appear at block scope. My understanding of this is that indicates I'm attempting to define in it in a function. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#define SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <new> // Needed for bad-alloc exception
#include <cstdlib> // Needed for the exit function
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SimpleVector {
        private:

        T *aptr; // To point to the allocated array
        int arraysize; // Number of elements in the array
        void memError(); // Handles memory allocation errors
        void subError(); // Handles subscripts out of range
public:

        SimpleVector()
                {
                aptr = 0; arraysize = 0;
                }

        SimpleVector(int s);

        SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &);

        ~SimpleVector();

        int size() const
                {
                return arraysize;
                }

        T getElementAt(int sub);

        T &operator[](const int &);


};

#endif //SIMPLEVECTOR_H

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int s)
{
        if(s<1)
                {
                arraysize=1;
                }

        else
                {
                arraysize=s;
                }

        try
                {
                aptr = new T [arraysize];
                }

        catch (bad_alloc)
                {
                memError();
                }

        for(int i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
                {
                aptr[i]=0;
                {
} 

template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::memError()
{

        cout<<"Error: cannot allocate memory."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

template <class T>
T SimpleVector<T>::getElementAt(int sub)
{
        return aptr[sub];
}

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::~SimpleVector()
{
        if(arraysize>0)
                {
                aptr.clear();
                aptr=aptr[0];
                }
}

template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::subError()
{

        cout<<"Subscripts out of range."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Then here are the errors I'm getting.

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
simplevector.h: In constructor ‘SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int)’:
simplevector.h:87:1: error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
 template <class T>
 ^
simplevector.h:99:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘template’
 template <class T>
 ^
simplevector.h:109:1: error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
 template <class T>
 ^
simplevector.h:122:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘template’
 template <class T>
 ^
main.cpp:9:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
main.cpp:47:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
main.cpp:47:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Any insight or help would be amazing!

Comment: Can you take the time to reformat the shown code so that it has clear, logical indentation? As is, the shown code is mostly unreadable and incomprehensible, due to its haphazard indentation. Most editors have an easy means to reindent the code logically. Use it. Maybe you'll even discover the typo in your code, that results in these compilation errors! But, in all cases, for people to help you they must be able to read the shown code.

Comment: There's a `{` that should be a `}` a few lines before the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int s)
```

there is a mismatch of opening and closing braces for the `for` loop at the last.

And in the destructor, you should clear the vector as `aptr->clear();`, because `aptr` is a pointer variable.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably missed or have too many brackets `{ }`. Check the closing `}` and opening `{` blocks of code and make sure there are always pair of them, especially look up before your erroneous line of code.

Especially at

```
for(int i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
{
    aptr[i]=0;
{
```